# Find max Date Value for a subqueried list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is admittedly atrocious code.  I'm looking to not only make it work, but make it work well. I would like to get the `max date` for each `Claim Adjustment Type Code`.

Current code:

```
SELECT   a.[Current ClaimID], a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code], a.[Claim Effective Date]
FROM #tmp_hic_dupes_list_final_not10 a
join   (select a.[Current ClaimID], a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code], a.[Claim Effective Date]
from #tmp_hic_dupes_list_final_not10 as a
where 
a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code] in (SELECT  a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
FROM
#tmp_hic_dupes_list_final_not10 b where 
a.[Current HIC #] = b.[Current HIC #] and
a.[Claim Type Code] = b.[Claim Type Code] and 
a.[Provider Oscar #] = b.[Provider Oscar #] and
a.[Claim From Date] = b.[Claim From Date] and
a.[Claim Thru Date] = b.[Claim Thru Date] and
a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code] = b.[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
HAVING 
COUNT(*) > 1)) b on a.[Current ClaimID] = b.[Current ClaimID]
--WHERE a.[Claim Effective Date] < b.[Claim Effective Date]
group by a.[Current ClaimID], a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code], a.[Claim Effective Date]
having a.[Claim Effective Date] = max(a.[Claim Effective Date])
```

Current reuslts:

```
[Current ClaimID]   [Claim Adjustment Type Code]    [Claim Effective Date]
37274993770           1                             2014-02-07 00:00:00.000
37274993771           2                             2014-02-07 00:00:00.000
37509451954           1                             2014-02-21 00:00:00.000
37509451955           2                             2014-02-21 00:00:00.000
38168035124           1                             2014-04-04 00:00:00.000
38168035125           2                             2014-04-04 00:00:00.000
```

Expected results:

```
[Current ClaimID]   [Claim Adjustment Type Code]    [Claim Effective Date]
38168035124           1                             2014-04-04 00:00:00.000
38168035125           2                             2014-04-04 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Rather than showing current result show the source data set that should lead to your expected result. It helps to understand the intended logic.

Comment: I don't know what "phi" means, but you don't have to show the real confidential data. Make up a fake sample that highlights the structure of the real data without showing the actual names/numbers/dates. Most likely `cross apply` is what you need here, but it is a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a RANK() function to the existing code, RANK() each group of type codes by descending date, and then in outer query, pick off just the records with rank = 1

```
SELECT [Current ClaimID], [Claim Adjustment Type Code], [Claim Effective Date] FROM (
SELECT   a.[Current ClaimID], a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code], a.[Claim Effective Date],
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code] ORDER BY a.[Claim Effective Date] DESC) AS RankClaimTypeByDate
FROM #tmp_hic_dupes_list_final_not10 a
join   (select a.[Current ClaimID], a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code], a.[Claim Effective Date]
from #tmp_hic_dupes_list_final_not10 as a
where 
a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code] in (SELECT  a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
FROM
#tmp_hic_dupes_list_final_not10 b where 
a.[Current HIC #] = b.[Current HIC #] and
a.[Claim Type Code] = b.[Claim Type Code] and 
a.[Provider Oscar #] = b.[Provider Oscar #] and
a.[Claim From Date] = b.[Claim From Date] and
a.[Claim Thru Date] = b.[Claim Thru Date] and
a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code] = b.[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
HAVING 
COUNT(*) > 1)) b on a.[Current ClaimID] = b.[Current ClaimID]
--WHERE a.[Claim Effective Date] < b.[Claim Effective Date]
group by a.[Current ClaimID], a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code], a.[Claim Effective Date]
having a.[Claim Effective Date] = max(a.[Claim Effective Date]) ) d WHERE RankClaimTypeByDate = 1  -- Select the 1st ranked record within each [Claim Adjustment Type Code]
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this would be to add a where clause that limits the result to those rows for which there does not exist any row with the same *Claim Adjustment Type Code* and a later *Claim Effective Date*.

Try adding this to your query:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM #tmp_hic_dupes_list_final_not10 
    WHERE [Claim Adjustment Type Code] = a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code] 
      AND [Claim Effective Date] > a.[Claim Effective Date]
)
```

Also, you can probably get rid of the last having clause as it doesn't seem to do anything (but without test data I'm not 100% sure).

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to join on a subset of the same data you're selecting from that grabs just the `MAX([Claim Effective Date])` for each `[Claim Adjustment Type Code]`.  This is more of an additional step on the results of the existing query rather than being a part of it, though (in case that's an option for you):

```
SELECT a.[Current ClaimID]
    ,a.[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
    ,a.[Claim Effective Date]
FROM #tmp_hic_dupes_list_final_not10 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT [ClaimAdjustment Type Code], MAX([Claim Effective Date]) AS MostRecentEffectiveDate
    FROM #tmp_hic_dupes_list_final_not10
    GROUP BY [ClaimAdjustment Type Code]) AS XYZ
ON a.[Claim Effective Date] = XYZ.MostRecentEffectiveDate
ORDER BY a.[Current ClaimID], a.[ClaimAdjustment Type Code]
```